# Why my cookie is lost when the browser is closed? (Expires set by javascript)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to set a permanent cookie by JavaScript. I have something like:

```
document.cookie = name+'='+value+";expires="+(new Date(2019, 1, 1)).toUTCString();
```

It does not work. The cookie disappears when the browser is closed. Why is that? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function setCookie(key, value) {  
   var expires = new Date();  
   expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + 31536000000); //1 year  
   document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();  
   }
```

I have just set to 1 Year and you can change it to your convinience.

Comment: It works on my localhost, but not on remote server. Any idea why?

Comment: Make sure that your "jquery.cookie.js" exists on the server and set the path if needed so that you can access it from you site.

Comment: I figure out. It's my bad. The cookie.js was not included in my upload script. how stupid ... thanks! your solution works

Answer (score 1):

I believe you literally have to set a number of days. So like 10000 or however long you want it to last.