# Flutter web remove cookies after browser closed

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have used [document.cookie](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.22.0/dart-html/Document/cookie.html) to save the cookie, it works fine when I am using the browser continuously, but when I close the browser and reopen it, the cookies get removed. help me.

this is code snipit how i m using cookies.

```
import 'dart:html';

class CookieManager {

  static addToCookie(String key, String value) {
    document.cookie = "$key=$value;";
  }

  static String getCookie(String key) {

    String cookies = document.cookie;
    List<String> listValues = cookies.isNotEmpty ? cookies.split(";") : List();
    String matchVal = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < listValues.length; i++) {
      List<String> map = listValues[i].split("=");
      String _key = map[0].trim();
      String _val = map[1].trim();
      if (key == _key) {
        matchVal = _val;
        break;
      }
    }
    return matchVal;
  }
}
```

Comment: In debug mode flutter opens chrome browser as a new instance without any profile. Could you try accessing the url couple of times from a normal instance where you usually browse. I suspect it will be saved.

Comment: do you want to remove the cookies or keep it. Your title is a bit misleading.

Comment: Then you probably need to set an expiry date. check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204224/why-my-cookie-is-lost-when-the-browser-is-closed-expires-set-by-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to provide a timer for the cookie

```
void addToCookie(String key,String value){
    document.cookie = "$key=$value; max-age=2592000; path=/;";}
```